# Cannot access 'kotlin.ranges.OpenEndRange' in IDEA and Kotlin 1.7.0

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

I have a Kotlin + Maven project which uses Kotlin 1.7.0. When I import the project in IDEA I see an 'error' (more on that later) in the `in` operator when used with an `IntRange`:

[image]

My IDEA version is the latest as of this writing (`Build #IU-223.7571.182, built on November 29, 2022`).

It looks like for some reason IDEA is trying to find the `OpenEndRange` type introduced in 1.7.20 (https://kotlinlang.org/docs/whatsnew1720.html#preview-of-the-operator-for-creating-open-ended-ranges), but my project is using 1.7.0 and the type doesn't exist.

I noticed that in IDEA preferences it uses a newer plugin and analyzer versions than 1.7.0:

[image]

When the project is compiled on the CLI with just maven, all works. Actually, it also builds and runs in IDEA, so the red underscore is somehow bogus and confusing.

Here is my `pom.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>idea_kotlin_test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <kotlin.version>1.7.0</kotlin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

and the sample code that shows the issue:

```kotlin
package com.example

import java.time.LocalDate
import java.time.temporal.ChronoField

fun foo(month: Int): Boolean {
    val start = LocalDate.now().get(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR) // as Int
    
    return month in (start..12) // <=== here
}

fun main() {
    println(foo(1))
}
```

I imported the project into IDEA by just choosing 'File' -> 'Open' and choosing the project folder, it detects everything automatically.

It looks as though IDEA somehow doesn't like the `LocalDate.get(TemporalField field)` call, or rather its return value. When I add `as Int`, the 'error' goes away but then `as Int` is greyed out as 'needless cast' (which I expect); the 'error' is also not shown when I just assign a hardcoded `Int` to the `start` `val`. I tried calling different Java methods returning `int` but to no avail, I couldn't reproduce the issue.

What is going on and how can I tell IDEA to stop showing this strange 'error'? Why is the `LocalDate.get(TemporalField)` method special?

[image]

Comment: I suspect this is because the IDE plugin version 1.7.20 is greater than the Maven plugin version. The best solution would be to use the Maven plugin version 1.7.20+.

Comment: I created an issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-24000/IDE-MISSINGDEPENDENCYSUPERCLASS-on-range-usage-with-1.7.0-stdlib-and-1.7.20-IDE-plugin

Comment: @AlexeyBelkov That was my suspicion as well, that's why I checked the plugin version. I agree the easiest solution would be to upgrade the version, but unfortunately, in my current project upgrading stuff, even if it makes total sense, is not a decision I can make myself in moments, there is a whole process behind it. Still, this seems like an IDEA/plugin issue.